# Zooming into Parametric Animation Plot that Uses InterpolatingFunctions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, animation

I have an interplanetary trajectory solver that calculates a spacecraft route from Earth to Mars, and I am trying to zoom into the spacecraft when it reaches its Mars intercept orbit but am having some trouble. I originally asked a question of a similar nature on these forums ([Zooming into animated plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47192/zooming-into-animated-plot)), but used a simple parametric function as an example, and although I was given a good answer, I was unable to translate that solution to the trajectory solver as it is a bit more involved. Here is a stripped down version of the code which shows the orbits of Earth (inner circle), Mars (outer circle) and the spacecraft (line joining the inner and outer circles). Although what I tried hasn't worked, if you look at the PlotRange code I used when making the trajectory animation, I used an if function to change the PlotRange and essentially "zoom-in" to the spacecraft when it got close to Mars; unfortunately this code did not work, but I have left it in as it is essentially what I want to do in pseudo-code if you will. Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(*Gravitational Constant*)
G = 6.672*10^-11;
(*Simulation running time*)
tmax = (800) (86400);
(*Spacecraft TOF between Earth and Mars*)
dt = (254) (86400);
(*Time at which Mid-course correction is applied*)
dtmcc = dt/2;
(*Mass of Sun, Earth, Mars and spacecraft*)
m[0] = 1.988544*10^30 ;(*Mass of Sun*)
m[1] = 5.97219*10^24 ;(*Mass of Earth*)
m[2] = 6.4185*10^23 ;(*Mass of Mars*)
m[3] = 1000;
(*Planetary radii of Sun, Earth and Mars*)
r[0] = 6.963*10^8 ;(*Mean radius of Sun*) 
r[1] = 6.37101 *10^6;(*Mean radius of Earth*) 
r[2] = 3.3899*10^6 ;(*Mean radius of Mars*)
(*Heliocentric positions of Earth and Mars on 26 November 2011*)
p[1] = 149597870700 {4.416639858432274*10^-1, 
   8.798967504313304*10^-1} ;
p[2] = 149597870700 {-8.159382724017646*10^-1, 1.414986880765974*10^0};
p[3] = {6.6078363676586365`*^10, 1.3162870491119447`*^11}
(*Heliocentric velocities of Earth and Mars on 26 November 2011*)
v[1] = 149597870700/
   86400 {-1.563974110293042*10^-2, 7.690252775639107*10^-3} ;
v[2] = 149597870700/
   86400 {-1.160326991502370*10^-2, -5.778933879736245*10^-3} ;

vLambert[1] = {-8473.224022968232`, -23353.77562466311`};
vLambert[2] = {17642.608238929563`, -11842.147739330356`};
mindr = 4.660029187323423`*10^6 + 1000000;
theta = 2.1223566349593104`;
v2x = 20874.193923950195`;
v2y = -11635.115234375`;

Soln = NDSolve[{
   x[1]''[t] == -((G m[0] x[1][t])/(x[1][t]^2 + y[1][t]^2)^(3/2)),
   y[1]''[t] == -((G m[0] y[1][t])/(x[1][t]^2 + y[1][t]^2)^(3/2)),
   x[2]''[t] == -((G m[0] x[2][t])/(x[2][t]^2 + y[2][t]^2)^(3/2)),
   y[2]''[t] == -((G m[0] y[2][t])/(x[2][t]^2 + y[2][t]^2)^(3/2)),
   x[3]''[t] == -((G m[0] x[3][t])/(x[3][t]^2 + y[3][t]^2)^(3/2))
   - (G m[1] (x[3][t]- x[1][t]))/((x[3][t] - x[1][t])^2 + (y[3][t] - y[1][t])^2)^(3/2)
   - (G m[2] (x[3][t] - x[2][t]))/((x[3][t] - x[2][t])^2 + (y[3][t] - y[2][t])^2)^(3/2),
   y[3]''[t] == -((G m[0] y[3][t])/(x[3][t]^2 + y[3][t]^2)^(3/2))
   - (G m[1] (y[3][t] - y[1][t]))/((x[3][t] - x[1][t])^2 + (y[3][t] - y[1][t])^2)^(3/2) 
   - (G m[2] (y[3][t] - y[2][t]))/((x[3][t] - x[2][t])^2 + (y[3][t] - y[2][t])^2)^(3/2),

   x[1][0] == p[1][[1]], y[1][0] == p[1][[2]], x[2][0] == p[2][[1]], 
   y[2][0] == p[2][[2]], x[3][0] == p[3][[1]], y[3][0] == p[3][[2]], 
   x[1]'[0] == v[1][[1]], y[1]'[0] == v[1][[2]], 
   x[2]'[0] == v[2][[1]], y[2]'[0] == v[2][[2]], 
   x[3]'[0] == v[1][[1]] + 3373.0439329044348`, 
   y[3]'[0] == v[1][[2]] + 10880.11479034743`, 
   WhenEvent[
    t == dtmcc, {x[3]'[t] -> vLambert[1][[1]], 
     y[3]'[t] -> vLambert[1][[2]]}], 
   WhenEvent[
    t == ((253*86400) + 81460), {x[3]'[t] -> 
      v2x - Sqrt[(G m[2])/mindr] Sin[theta], 
     y[3]'[t] -> v2y + Sqrt[(G m[2])/mindr] Cos[theta]}]}, {x[1][
    t], y[1][t], x[2][t], y[2][t], x[3][t], y[3][t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.001, AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 15, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10000000]

Orbits = ParametricPlot[{{x[1][t], y[1][t]}, {x[2][t], 
     y[2][t]}, {x[3][t], y[3][t]}} /. Soln, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}, {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}}]

OrbitAnimation = 
 Animate[ParametricPlot[{{x[1][t], y[1][t]}, {x[2][t], y[2][t]}, 
 {x[3][t], y[3][t]}}/. Soln /. t -> a, {t, 0, a}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange ->If[t>=253*86400, {{x[3][t]-1000000,x[
   3][t]+1000000},{y[3][t]-1000000,y[3][t]+1000000}},{{-0.25*10^12,
   0.25*10^12},{-0.25*10^12,0.25*10^12}}]], {a, 0, tmax}, 
  AnimationRate -> 1000000]
```

[image]

Comment: Unless I overlooked something, everything is fine, there is just a scoping issue. Symbols `t`, `x`, and `y` are not available where you set the PlotRange option value. `a` and `Soln` are, use them like you have done in the first argument of your ParametricPlot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the `/. Soln /. t->a` rule that you apply inside `ParametricPlot` to your parameters in `PlotRange` as well. The error occurred because the expression given to `PlotRange` didn't evaluate. It would just say `x[3][somevalue]` because x had not been replaced by the corresponding interpolating function. After that I realized that the list had been wrapped with an extra `List` in the process of doing those replacements, so I wrapped the expression in `First`.

```
OrbitAnimation = 
 Animate[ParametricPlot[{{x[1][t], y[1][t]}, {x[2][t], 
       y[2][t]}, {x[3][t], y[3][t]}} /. Soln /. t -> a, {t, 0, a}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> If[
     a >= 253*86400,
     First[{
         {x[3][t] - 1000000, x[3][t] + 1000000},
         {y[3][t] - 1000000, y[3][t] + 1000000}
         } /. Soln /. t -> a],
     {
      {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12},
      {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}
      }
     ]
   ], {a, 0, tmax}, AnimationRate -> 1000000]
```

In response to the comment about transitioning into the new Mars centric view:

```
switchViewLimit = 253*86400;
transitionPeriod = 2 1000000;
transitionRatio[a_] := Min[(a - switchViewLimit)/transitionPeriod, 1]
OrbitAnimation = Animate[
  ParametricPlot[
   {{x[1][t], y[1][t]}, {x[2][t], y[2][t]}, {x[3][t], y[3][t]}} /. 
     Soln /. t -> a, {t, 0, a},
   AxesLabel -> {x, y},
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotRange -> If[
     a >= switchViewLimit,
     First[
      {
         {transitionRatio[a] x[3][t] - 0.25*10^12, 
          transitionRatio[a] x[3][t] + 0.25*10^12},
         {transitionRatio[a] y[3][t] - 0.25*10^12, 
          transitionRatio[a] y[3][t] + 0.25*10^12}
         } /. Soln /. t -> a
      ], {
      {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12},
      {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}
      }]], {a, 0, tmax}, AnimationRate -> 1000000]
```

Comment: +1 for the effort :D I didn't even try to read the OP's code.. :(

Comment: Thanks very much Pickett. I apologise for the amount of code, but I tried to cut it down as much as possible and that's about 20% of it.

Comment: @user7388 No worries, it actually wasn't a problem for me because I realized from the beginning where the error was. Theo Tiger did too, which proves your question was manageable after all.

Comment: @Pickett is there a way to make the zoom transition from the heliocentric view to the areocentric view (mars-centered) instead of it occuring instantaneously?

Comment: @user7388 I've added a piece of code that addresses this. `transitionPeriod` determines how fast it transitions to the new view.